# Is it possible to purchase an On-Demand AWS Instance through an API call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've found out that an API call can be used to purchase a [Scheduled AWS Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_PurchaseScheduledInstances.html).
I haven't come across a similar request to buy an On-Demand Instance, though.
Is there a workaround, or was this particular call omitted on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-Demand instances are the **default** if you start a new instance, there is no need for separate purchasing as they will automatically be billed per hour/minute/second depending on the Operating System.